# Combine two JSON responses together in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

In my CakePHP app I do some stuff in the beforeFilter to pass extra JSON data with the response about the user or authentication etc.

For example:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Auth->allow(array('index'));

    // If the request is either JSON or XML
    if ( $this->params['ext'] == 'json' || $this->params['ext'] == 'xml' )
    {
        if( $this->Auth->user() )
        {
            // User is logged in so send userdata and usual response will also be passed
            $response = array('meta' => 
                array(
                    'auth' => true,
                    'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
                )
            );
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else
        {
            $requiresAuth = !in_array($this->params['action'], $this->Auth->allowedActions);
            if ($requiresAuth)
            {
                $response = array('meta' => 
                    array(
                        'auth' => false
                    )
                );
                echo json_encode($response);
                exit; // exit so no other responses go through
            }
            else
            {
                // Send JSON usual response
                $response = array('meta' => 
                    array(
                        'auth' => false
                    )
                );
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    }

    parent::beforeFilter();

}
```

This is used to build my RESTful API for a mobile app. The issue here is that the full returned JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "auth": false,
    }
} {
    "posts": [{
        "Post": {
            "id": "136",
            "user_id": "8",
            "datetime": "2012-09-11 15:49:52",
            "modified": "2012-09-16 15:31:38",
            "title": "Where is good to eat in New York?",
            "slug": "Where_is_good_to_eat_in_New_York",
            "content": "Preferably italian or mexican and with a good atmosphere.\r\n\r\nAlso within the **Manhattan** area!",
            "status": "1",
            "promoted": "0",
            "latitude": "53.6570794",
            "longitude": "-1.8277604"
        },...
```

As you can see the two JSON objects don't combine together properly... How do I fix this?

Using CakePHP 2.3

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, I have not used much of the restful cake stuff but... The view turns the array into the json object right? if so, can you change your  `echo json_encode($response);` to `$this->request->data['meta']['auth'] = false;` ?

Comment: You are outputting the `meta` response in your before filter and then presumably outputting the `posts` response in a method in your `PostsController` but you haven't provided that part. You shouldn't be echoing in your controller anyway. Personally I'd set a flag in the `beforeFilter` and then in whatever method you are outputting posts, check for it and add the appropriate meta information to the same array (merge them then `json_encode` them).

Comment: This needs to be global though as in for all methods in all controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

1) don't echo anything from your beforeFilter() functions - it will break unit testing.

2) create a protected variable in app_controller called $extra_data;

3) where you have your echo statements, simply set $extra_data to $response;

4) in your controller action that echoes out your main json, check for ! empty($this->extra_data) and if that's true, merge your main action response with the extra data and set that to your view to echo as json there.

Comment: Can you show how I would merge them? The return I have in my method is: `$this->set('posts', '_serialize');` Cheers

Comment: Also how would I handle the exit for when I ONLY want to pass the auth failed and no other data without having to do a check in each method saying yes or no before erroring out.

Comment: array_merge() should do the trick, or just set $_serialize to $this->extra_data before adding your extra data to $serialize. I would avoid using exit, and just render a view specifically for error messages before returning from the beforeFilter function

Answer (score 0):

Try json_encode(array_merge($response));